# how to use fs for saving and loading matrices to and from text files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have such a problem. I need to create a pair of functions for saving and loading matrices to and from text files.

1. I need to creat a fnction saveMatrixToFile(matrix, path), that
   writes the contents of the argument matrix into a file located at
   the given path.
2. then to create a fnction loadMatrixFromFile(path) function, that
   returns a matrix filled with the contents of a file that has been
   created using the saveMatrixToFile() function.

Here is a part of my code, but I'm not sure if it's right or not.

```
const fs = require('fs');
function saveToTextFile(matrix) {  
fs.writeFile("./new.txt", matrix, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("saved to textfile1");
    }
});

console.log("next");
}
```

Comment: well, did you test it? Do you get in new.txt the contents of the variable `matrix`? When you read it back ... do you get the original data back? 
We cant answer these questions for you. If you have other questions, post them.

Answer (score 0):

How are your matrices defined? Would a simple

```
JSON.stringify(matrix);
```

and

```
JSON.parse(matrixJsonStringFromFile);
```

already do the trick?